# laravel eloquent union different column

Tags: laravel, select, eloquent

I want join this table, but the columns is different.

```
$user_plays_aas = DB::table('user_plays')
->leftJoin('user_plays_aas', 'user_plays.id', '=', 'user_plays_aas.user_play_id')
->leftJoin('aas_games', function($join) {
            $join->on('user_plays_aas.game_id', '=', 'aas_games.game_id')
                 ->on('user_plays_aas.prd_id', '=', 'aas_games.prd_id');
                })
                ->where('user_plays_aas.txn_id', $gameid);

$user_plays_pp = DB::table('user_plays')
->leftJoin('user_plays_pp', 'user_plays.id', '=', 'user_plays_pp.user_play_id')
->leftJoin('pp_games', 'user_plays_pp.gameID', '=', 'pp_games.gameID')
->where('user_plays_pp.roundid', $gameid);

$Union= $user_plays_aas
        ->unionAll($user_plays_pp );
```

How i make same columns $user_plays_aas and $user_plays_pp ? Cause Diff1 or Diff2 read as columns not as data, so make error.

```
$user_plays_aas->select('Same1','Same2', 'Diff1 as PP1', 'AAS1');
$user_plays_pp ->select('Same1','Same2', 'PP1', 'Diff2 as AAS1');
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `dummy_data`? Is it a variable?  Can you add an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, like "variable/ i type that data".
I want union 5 tables but the column is different, so i want make it same.
How to i can make that columns same ? Cause eloquent read variable/type as column name.

Comment: It still unclear, please edit your question to provide an example - as well please format your code

Comment: I think i mean is add column dummy.